# AWS EKS with Fargate - Kube-system pods not schedule on fargate node

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have a kubernetes cluster in aws eks with fargate profiles. When I'm trying to run aws load balancer controller or the metrics server in the kube-system namespace, the pods are not getting scheduled on the fargate nodes and are picked by the default-scheduler. But I try to deploy them on the default namespace they are picked by the fargate-scheduler are are getting deployed on the fargate nodes.

Here is my CF template for kube-system fargate profile:

```html
EKSFargateProfileKubeSystem:
    Type: 'AWS::EKS::FargateProfile'
    DependsOn:
      - EKSCluster
      - EKSIAMFargateRole
    Properties:
      FargateProfileName: kube-system
      ClusterName: !Sub 'my-cluster-${Stage}'
      PodExecutionRoleArn:
        "Fn::GetAtt": [ "EKSIAMFargateRole", "Arn" ]
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet01
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet02
      Selectors:
        - Namespace: kube-system
          Labels:
            - Key: k8s-app
              Value: kube-dns
```

Please suggest If I'm missing anything and why the fargate profile for kube-system is not working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
...
Selectors:
- Namespace: kube-system
  Labels:  # <-- here
  - Key: k8s-app
    Value: kube-dns
```

You have `Labels` setup which means only pod with the labels (k8s-app: kube-dns)will be running on Fargate. Remove the `Labels` requirement and all pods in your cluster `kube-system` namespace will run on Fargate.